# Writing for the saxophone

Tags: sheet-music, composition, saxophone

Are there special symbols or text instructions that are more or less specific to the saxophone?
What difficulties or peculiarities are there with the saxophone that a composer or arranger would need to think about when writing sheet music?

Comment: Do not write chords!

Comment: Welcome! These are great things to find out, but as Stack Exchange questions, it might be nice to edit them a bit. First of all, it's good to stick to one question at a time; "sax-specific symbols" is a way narrower field, and easier to answer than "what does a composer need to know to write for sax"! Second, although not required, it's nice to show any research you've already done or what you already know (helps narrow the question more and avoid telling you what you don't need to hear). I'd recommend editing to stick with the first question for now, and maybe elaborate on it?

Comment: @Tom What about multiphonics?

Comment: @lazy Do not write triads!

Comment: I’d vote to close this question because, while the question *does* deal with interesting topics, is too broad and generic to allow a valid and proper answer. For this specific topic, you should really consider asking your question to an *experienced* sax player. As a percussionist I know that most composers write their music based on *generic* suggestions that do *not* consider the experience of those who actually *do* know how the instrument should or could be played. While the question could fit MSE, it's so generic that there's no way to provide valid suggestions for a proper answer.

Comment: Specifically, have you *ever* talked to a saxophonist? Have you ever had a (long and satisfying) talking session with them, where you discussed the possibilities of the instruments, the capabilities of a "standard" player and their ability to understand non-standard notation? You cannot write for an instrument you don't *really* know, otherwise you'll end up with parts that are possibly unplayable, or that would be played in a way that's not what you would expect.

Comment: Well, apart from extended technique it is quite straightforward. There are just a few intervals that are hard to play and should thus be used sparingly. For example transposing low c - low d# is a bit tricky, also passages that switch between high base register and low alto register very often will be harder to perform.

Comment: Do you care exclusively about notation unique to saxophone, or are you willing to discuss notation unique to wind instruments (e.g. fluttertongue) or perhaps single-reed woodwind instruments (e.g. you're willing to accept notation exclusively in saxophone and clarinet sheet music)?

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question and I'm voting to reopen. / Don't woodwind players in general prefer keys with flats over keys with sharps?  Also I vaguely remember from my son's saxophone phase that big jumps were challenging -- we saw this in a transcription of a Bach cello suite.  What was easy on the cello (high melody alternating with low open string) was hard on the barry sax (and vice versa).

Comment: If it were just a *little* narrower in scope, I'd vote to reopen it. Maybe "saxophone-specific notation symbols" instead of the lifetime-to-master "quirks of writing for saxophone"? Depending on exactly what OP's intent is.